# agregar array a FormData() y enviar por ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Necesito agregar a mi formData un array o objeto para poder pasarlo por ajax a php, este es mi código:
el tema es que cuando realizo un var_dump() en el archivo php no obtengo el resultado deseado

```
var dato = new FormData();
var acciones = [];
var checked = '';

        $("#subMenuRow" + $(this).data('id_submenu') + " :input ").each(function(){

                console.log('-> action' + $(this).data('action'));
                console.log('-> checked' + $(this).prop('checked'));

                if($(this).attr('checked')){
                    checked = 1;
                }else{
                    checked = 0;
                }

                acciones[$(this).data('action')] = checked;

        });

            dato.append('id_submenu', $(this).data('id_submenu'));
            dato.append('accion', $(this).data('accion'));
            dato.append('acciones_menu', acciones);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                contentType:false,
                dataType:'json',
                data: dato,
                processData:false,
                cache:false,
                url : " contents/relaciones.backend/functions_ajax.php/",
                success : function (result) {
                    $("div#contenido_modal").html(result);
                },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                }
        });
```

espero se entienda, muchas gracias por la atención

Comment: cual es el resultado que esperas? y cual resultado te arroja actualmente?

Comment: Gracias por responder.
Console.log(acciones), en jquery me devuelve:
`Array(5)
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
length: 5`

lo que necesito,  el id de la acción y el estado (1 - 0) hasta aca bien.


 del lado de php, por POST estoy recibiendo:
`
$_POST: Array[3]
id_submenu: 181
accion: asignar
**acciones_menu: ,1,1,1,1**`

el indice acciones_menu no contiene lo que necesito, id de acción y estado.
Muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: puedes agregar la parte de php? y editar tu pregunta agregando los resultados que esperas, ya que no interpreto bien lo que deseas

Answer (score 0):

Lo harías de la siguiente manera:

```
dato.append('acciones[0]', accion1);
dato.append('acciones[1]', accion2);
```

Como es un arreglo puedes recorrerlo y armarlo de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:

```
for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
  formData.append('photos['+i+']', files[i])
}
```

El ejemplo anterior lo use para una subida de archivos múltiples.